# Why is EnvDTE.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel = Nothing?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vba, visual-studio-macros

I wrote a VSMacro (in VS2010) that parses a solution and adds try and catch statements to cpp files. It's been working fine up until now. I had to reformat my pc and reinstall VS2010 and now it crashes. Here's a snippet from the macro.

```
Sub Foo(ByVal file As EnvDTE.ProjectItem)
    Dim fileCM As EnvDTE.FileCodeModel
    fileCM = file.FileCodeModel
End Sub
```

I've checked to see if that file is a valid object, and it does point to a cpp file. But for some reason file.FileCodeModel = Nothing. Why would FileCodeModel be Nothing?

Answer (score 0):

There are several scenarios in Visual Studio where a `ProjectItem` will not return a `FileCodeModel` object.  For example if the `ProjectItem` points to a folder or a non-code file item in solution explorer.

Can you verify what the `ProjectItem` represents in this scenario.  In particular

- Is it pointing to a file?
- What type of project is this in (Web, console app, etc ...)?

Comment: like i said in my question, the `ProjectItem` points to a cpp file.

Comment: @Ernesto, what type of C++ project is this.  Native, pure managed, C++/CLI, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it happens when the project is not compilable. You need to try to build the solution first.